# Change ports on running Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Is there any way of changing the opened ports in an Azure Container Instance that is smarter (and faster) than deleting the container and creating a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, there is no way fast than deleting and create a new one. Actually, the update action is a little faster than delete and create a new one. But the ports are not the property you can update. You can get more details in [Properties that require container delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update#properties-that-require-container-delete).

In addition, the update action is also a redeploy process from the existing group configuration. Totally, it's not much faster than delete and creates a new one. See [Update containers in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update#properties-that-require-container-delete).